# how to retrieve the id just created in the database in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

how do I retrieve the id that was just created in the database, when I press the save button, the data is created, and I want to retrieve the id from that data

this my controller code

```
$cart= new cart;
        $cart->user_id = $request->user_id;
        $cart>vendor_name = $request->vendor_name;
$cart->save();
```

I want to retrieve the id of the data just created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After saving you can access id like:

```
$cart->id
```

This will be the id of the card you have recently created.

Answer (score 0):

```
$cart= new cart;
        $cart->user_id = $request->user_id;
        $cart>vendor_name = $request->vendor_name;
$cart->save();

$cart->id; //here you still have access to the data and you can access the id like this.
```

> Same thing goes to the *`user_id`* and any other field, you can access them like this: `$cart-> user_id;`

Answer (score 0):

All information you cation access by this $cart.after saving this you just

```
$cart->id (to get id)
$cart->user_id(to get user_id)
```